# Which transition_* to use for animating map with gganimate?

Tags: ggplot2, gganimate

I want to make a animated choropleth map of US counties with the number of confirmed COVID-19 cases over time (yes, yet another coronavirus plot). [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12IVkIRbqYVFezWhmsahU8G2qtm1xezi-/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a three day selection of the data (suggestions for a more permanent place to host it are welcome). Here is the code that creates the static map  (comment the filter to include all dates):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(scales)

p <- part_data %>%
  filter(date == as.Date("2020-03-30")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = confirmed_new), color = "grey70", size = 0.05) + 
  geom_path(data = state_map, colour = "black") +
  coord_map() +
  scale_fill_distiller(trans = "log10", direction = 1, palette = "YlOrRd", na.value = "white", limits = c(1, 1E4), labels = comma)
```

Which gives this pretty nice plot:
[image: Map plot]

But how do I now make an animation that moves through the dates? I tried

```
p +
  transition_time(date)
```

and

```
p + 
  transition_states(date)
```

but in both cases R just seems to freeze, before the rendering progress bar even appears, and after a while I get the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 128.0 Mb`. The problem is that I don't know if I'm even using the correct approach here. In the `gganimate` documentation I read that the `group` aesthetic is used to link rows that belong to the same graphic element, in this case county. But `group` is also used by `ggplot` itself to make the plot, could that be the issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that `transition_states` also renders transitions between the dates. I think that explains why it took so long to render and why I ran into memory problems. Using `transition_manual` I got it to work as I expected:

```
p + 
  transition_manual(frames = date)
```